# FirebaseUI RecycleView Search Not Working

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebaseui

Here Is my code for **SearchGetterSetter.java**:

```
package com.me.Admin;

public class SearchGetterSetter {

String fname;

public SearchGetterSetter(String fname) {
    this.fname = fname;
}

public String getFname() {
    return fname;
}

public void setFname(String fname) {
    this.fname = fname;
}
}
```

here is my code for SearchUserActivity.java

```
package com.me.Admin;

  import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
  import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
  import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
  import android.view.LayoutInflater;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.ViewGroup;
  import android.widget.EditText;
  import android.widget.ImageButton;
  import android.widget.TextView;
  import android.widget.Toast;

  import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerAdapter;
  import com.firebase.ui.database.FirebaseRecyclerOptions;
  import com.google.firebase.FirebaseException;
  import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
  import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
  import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
  import com.infoters.killansfitnessstudio.R;
  public class SearchUserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText SearchTxt;
private ImageButton SearchBtn;
private RecyclerView SearchRV;

private DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_user);

    mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
    SearchTxt = findViewById(R.id.SearchUserTxt);
    SearchBtn = findViewById(R.id.SearchUserBtn);
    SearchRV = findViewById(R.id.SearchUserRV);
    SearchRV.setHasFixedSize(true);
    SearchRV.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    SearchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String searchText = SearchTxt.getText().toString();
            firebaseUserSearch(searchText);

        }
    });

}

private void firebaseUserSearch(String searchText) {

    Query firebaseSearchQuery = mUserDatabase.child("fname");

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<SearchGetterSetter> response = new 
FirebaseRecyclerOptions.
            Builder<SearchGetterSetter> 
    ().setQuery(firebaseSearchQuery,SearchGetterSetter.class).build();
    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<SearchGetterSetter,UserViewHolder> Fire = new 
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<SearchGetterSetter, UserViewHolder>(response){
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup 
viewGroup, int i) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.search_user_item, viewGroup, false);
            return new UserViewHolder(view);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserViewHolder holder, int 
      position, @NonNull SearchGetterSetter model) {
            holder.fName.setText(model.getFname());
        }

    };

    Fire.notifyDataSetChanged();
    SearchRV.setAdapter(Fire);
}

public class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView fName;
    public UserViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        fName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.SUTxt);

    }
}

}
```

I want to search fname from Firebase realtime database. On Search buttton press I'm calling `firebaseUserSearch()` method.

I tried couple of methods but nothing works for me. I guess im doing FirebaseRecycleViewAdapter wrongly. I referred [this](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/README.md#using-firebaseui-to-populate-a-recyclerview).where am I going wrong?

EDIT:

Here my Database structure[image: Database Stucture]

Updated Code:

```
public class SearchUserActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private EditText SearchTxt;
private ImageButton SearchBtn;
private RecyclerView SearchRV;

private DatabaseReference mUserDatabase;

private FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<SearchGetterSetter,UserViewHolder> Fire;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search_user);

    mUserDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("users");
    SearchTxt = findViewById(R.id.SearchUserTxt);
    SearchBtn = findViewById(R.id.SearchUserBtn);
    SearchRV = findViewById(R.id.SearchUserRV);
   //        SearchRV.setHasFixedSize(true);
    SearchRV.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));


    SearchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String searchText = SearchTxt.getText().toString();
            firebaseUserSearch(searchText);
            Toast.makeText(SearchUserActivity.this, "Clicked", 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

}

private void firebaseUserSearch(String searchText) {

    Query firebaseSearchQuery = mUserDatabase.orderByChild("fname").startAt(searchText).endAt(searchText + "\uf8ff");

    FirebaseRecyclerOptions<SearchGetterSetter> response = new FirebaseRecyclerOptions.
            Builder<SearchGetterSetter>().setQuery(firebaseSearchQuery,SearchGetterSetter.class).build();

    Fire = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<SearchGetterSetter, UserViewHolder>(response){
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public UserViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
            View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext())
                    .inflate(R.layout.search_user_item, viewGroup, false);
            return new UserViewHolder(view);
        }
        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull UserViewHolder holder, 
       int position, @NonNull SearchGetterSetter model) {
            holder.fname.setText(model.getFname());
        }

    };

    Fire.startListening();
    Fire.notifyDataSetChanged();
    SearchRV.setAdapter(Fire);

}

public static class UserViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    private TextView fname;
    public UserViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        fname = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.SUTxt);
    }
}


}
```

Comment: @rishikesh_07 Have you checked my answer? got solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your this statement:

```
Query firebaseSearchQuery = mUserDatabase.child("fname");
```

Should be

```
Query firebaseSearchQuery = mUserDatabase.orderByChild("fname").equals(searchText);
```

As I saw your code, you haven't used **searchText** variable in your query.

Comment: Use `.orderByChild("fname")` instead `.orderByChild("users")`

Comment: is their any way to get UID in recycle view?

Comment: You have take one field like `uid` to store it while storing data.

Comment: can you help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

To create a search feature, you need to create a query that should look like this:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference usersRef = rootRef.child("users");
Query query = usersRef.orderByChild("fname").equalTo(searchedText);
```

So everytime you search for a name, you should return a new query object. So every time you want to filter on a new condition, you will need to:

1. Create a **new** query based on the new searched text:

   ```
   Query query = usersRef.orderByChild("name").equalTo(searchedText);
   ```
2. Attach a listener to this new created query.
3. Create a new adapter with the results of this new created query, or update the existing one using `notifydatasetchanged()` method.